Why is sRGB red (#FF0000) incorrectly converted to #EA3323 in Display P3 and then to #d84532 in my Android screen app?
I'm developing an Android app (in Delphi) that loads an image with a pure red color (#FF0000) in the sRGB color space. The image is then decoded into a bitmap with inPreferredColorSpace set to Display P3.
Here’s what I’m doing:
Load an sRGB image with #FF0000:
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredColorSpace = ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.DISPLAY_P3);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);
Convert the bitmap into an OpenGL texture and draw it on a SurfaceTexture.

The Problem: When loading the image, I expect the sRGB red #FF0000 to be converted to its Display P3 equivalent, #EA3323. Instead, when I render the image, I end up with the color #d84532 (#d84532 is the conversion of the sRGB #EA3323 color to Display P3). So It seems that the red (#FF0000) was first converted to #EA3323 in Display P3, and then incorrectly converted again to #d84532
Why is this double conversion happening? Is this related to how OpenGL or SurfaceTexture handles color spaces, and if so, how can I configure it to avoid this double conversion?
Any advice or explanations would be really helpful!

How are you loading the texture? If you are using glTexImage2D/ glTexSubImage2D, then what format did you specify?

In Delphi, #FF0000 represents full-intensity, pure blue. The order of in Delphi is blue, green red (mnemonic: #BBGGRR). See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.UITypes.TColor

In addition to the texture configuration, how was your EGL window surface set up?

@MatthiasB: I believe that in FMX applications, they use RRGGBB format for colours. Android apps in Delphi are using FMX.

@dev.bmax I use glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Texture.Width, Texture.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nil);

@solidpixel IT's quite complicated to say you as it's many params to create the eGL window surface, i can just say you i do not see any think particular inside regarding the conversion of sRGB to Display P3

Where do you draw the image? SurfaceTexture is not a view. Maybe SurfaceView or TextureView? Also, what happens if you don't change inPreferredColorSpace?

OpenGL ES is generally going to be expecting either linear or sRGB input data, it has no native support for P3 textures and I'm not aware of any mobile hardware that reads P3 natively either.

Why is this double conversion happening?

Educated guess: you are manually converting it to P3, OpenGL ES reads it as non-P3 linear, and then the output from your shader was converted to P3 by the display subsystem because you'd configured a P3 window surface?
Why do you think you need to convert a non-P3 input image to P3 when you load it? Nothing about your glTexImage2D() call says anything about this being P3 - it's just a normal linear RGB8 texture.
